# For an app hosted on meteor.com, would it be reasonable to use a proxy to add SSL and a custom domain?

Tags: nginx, proxy, meteor

First, let me explain why. I've had some rough luck with third party meteor hosting providers. But I'd really rather not run my own servers (I have a meteor app running with SSL on digital ocean, so I know how to do that, I just would rather dedicated professionals run as much of my infrastructure as possible). From what I can see, meteor.com hosting is wonderful, with the caveat of not being able to have a custom domain with ssl.

So, would it make sense to put up an nginx server that just proxied https://example.com to https://example.meteor.com? For starters, would that work, and if it did, would it be performant?

Comment: no it doesn't make sense since `https://example.meteor.com` is still public accessible

Comment: i don't care about hiding the meteor.com domain or the fact that it is hosted there -- just having my services accessible from my own domain.

Comment: but it means you have to host your own nginx server just for proxying... I think it would make more sense just redirect your masked domain to `https://example.meteor.com`

Answer (score 2):

For your info, **Meteor** has a roadmap to roll out **Galaxy** (managed "meteor deploy" to your own servers) in list Under consideration for 1.1+. And it should be a perfect choice for you. Here is their [Trello](https://trello.com/c/FMdB7GAu/78-galaxy-managed-meteor-deploy-to-your-own-servers)

> This is MDG's commercial product -- a managed cloud platform for
>   deploying Meteor apps. You have control of the underlying hardware
>   (you own the servers or the EC2 instances, and Galaxy manages them for
>   you).
>
> General Availability for Galaxy will be sometime after 1.0, since we
>   want to focus on Meteor 1.0 and get it out as quickly as possible.

So in the mean time if you just care about using your own domain, you can use something like *Domain name forwarding* which lets you automatically direct your domain name's visitors to a different website. And *Masking* prevents visitors from seeing your domain name forwarding by keeping your domain name in the Web browser's address bar.

Also in your case, you don't necessarily need to add SSL as **Meteor** has already got one when you deploy your apps. Just try input the url in your browser with `https://yourappnamehere.meteor.com` and you can see a SSL certificate is already in place.